# Resize textarea based on lines of text

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function AutoGrowTextArea(textField) {
        if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight) {
            textField.style.height = textField.scrollHeight + "px";
            if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight) {
                textField.style.height =
    (textField.scrollHeight * 2 - textField.clientHeight) + "px";
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" runat="server">
  <input type = "text" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)"  style="width:700px; height:20px" />
   </form>
       </body>
```

Hey Guys, i have a script with which i can increase the size of a text area, one line at a time, just like facebook's comment box. But here is the problem:
I want to apply this in a text box, instead of a text area, and i have tried that too, but what happens is, the whole text area increases it's height each time i press a key...and that is definitely the behavior i do not require...
(all the semantics is correct, might have lost some while pasting it here...)
So can anyone help me out with this?
Regards...

Answer (score 1):

Replace "height" with "width" everywhere, even in "scrollHeight" and so on.

Comment: hey this just increases the width of the text box in the horizontal direction, i just want to increase the height of the textBox

Comment: Then use a `<textarea>` element, not an `<input>`.